# Python script to highlight incorrect data

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting output from a REST API and I managed to get this sent to Excel using Pandas which is working fine.

I need to figure out how to add some more logic to the extract. We basically have 7 columns:
Incident
Description
Assigned Group
Assignee
Status
Service
CI

I have a predefined list of Service and CI.
So if Service = Risk
Then CI must = RMP or SAP or Aravo

If the above is not true I need to highlight or alert on this. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

I tried using Excel IF statements but I am unable to figure out how to add the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask and the `styler`:

```
m = (df['Service'] == 'Risk') & (df['CI'].isin(['RMP', 'SAP', 'Aravo']))

(df.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(m, '', 'background-color: red'))
   .to_excel('data.xlsx', index=False))
```

Output:

```
>>> m
0     True  # Everything is ok
1    False  # Something wrong
2     True
dtype: bool
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Corralien.  This is exactly what I needed will test and provide a smaple.

Comment: Thanks Corralien my code is working. Now I have a new challenge, I need to figure out how to add a 2nd boolean mask or add more logic to the 1st one. Basically I have more Services and CI's. Will ask that on a new question as the ask for this question was solved by you. Thanks